# How to assert if a temporary file with name generated at runtime is deleted or not?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, junit, jboss-arquillian

I am writing a arquillian test case for my code. The method I am testing from my arquillian will actually create a  temporary file on the file system with a unique name. Before the method exits the file is deleted. I want to assert if the file is deleted or not. How can I achieve this when I don't know the file name except the location where it will be created?

Comment: Can you control the place it is created? If so, create a temporary folder (using JUnit rules) and ask the file to be created there. Then you can check the folder is empty afterwards.

Comment: @Duncan I have control over the folder. Thank you. :)